# IBM x3650 M1 SATA support up to 2 Tb

Tags: raid, ibm, sas, sata, firmware

I have an IBM x3650 (M1 [i think because of DDR2 rams]), an as i know it only support SATA hard drvies only up to 1 Tb.

Is there any RAID controller firmware/BIOS update which can give the server 2 tb hard drives support?

And how can is update it?

Thanks.

Ewert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The M1's only support drives up to 1TB and the full list is found here: [X3650 M1 compatibility guide](http://www-03.ibm.com/systems/info/x86servers/serverproven/compat/us/xseries_old/x3650.html)

There's not a ServerProven controller there with firmware that would support anything beyond 1TB.

Trying to go beyond or circumvent the compatibility guide IMO would be against proper Server Administration practices for a production environment.